# GOG Screenshot Location

Tags: gog, duke-nukem-3d

I got Duke Nukem 3D with GOG at Christmas and I have only just got round to playing it.

I have discovered <kbd>F12</kbd> creates a screenshot but I can't find the save location. Can anyone point me to the correct folder and what format are the screenshots normally saved in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have paid closer attention. The screenshots are saved in the root game folder. In my instance:

```
C:\GOG Games\Duke Nukem 3D
```

The file format they are in are `.PCX` and follow the naming convention:

```
DUKE0000.PCX
```

The `.PCX` files open fine in Photoshop and GiMP to be converted to something more modern and portable.

Comment: Note that this is Duke Nukem's own screenshot functionality. It's not provided by GOG. That's why it's located in the game's directory and why it's in an old obsolete format. As an alternative you can use DOSBox's screenshot functionality by pressing CTRL-F5. The files use the modern PNG format and are saved in the `capture` subdirectory of the game directory.

Comment: THe `ctrl` + `f5` thing worked brilliantly definitely post it as an answer!